# How to put entire txt file content inside one variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a generated report stored in a `.txt` file, which I need to put inside an email body.

I tried to use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) for the email, but we have security software which prevents it's use. I need therefore to use [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

I tried this [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), but it doesn't work:

```
set /P file=<<Result.txt
start "" "mailto:mail@gmail.com?subject=test&body=%file%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Work in progress.*

Have you tested if the file even goes into variable?
I can see a small typo in your code. I've just tested and it should be

```
set /P file=<Result.txt
```

Second problem is: it reads only the first line. It can be helped with this:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set file=
for /f "delims=" %%i in (Result.txt) do set file=!file! %%i

start "" "mailto:mail@gmail.com?subject=test&body=%file%"
EndLocal
```

But it will write everything in one line.

Comment: Thanks @Diodak, do you know any way to break the line, and I get it the same way it is on the file?

Comment: @AroqueR I spend a lot of time testing different solutions, because there's a lot of questions how to do it. Sorry, nothing worked for me.